# Google Sheets keep max value constant

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Refer the sheet in the figure
[image]

For the H column, I want Hj = Gj+MAX(F)-Fj , where j = row number.
The given formula works for the second row, but when I drag to other rows, MAX value also changes.  I want MAX(F2:F8) to be constant and other values to change. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Fix the max range like this `F$2:F$8` (`$` fixes the range).

Instead of dragging the formula down from cell `H2`, you could use an `arrayformula` in cell `H2`:

`=arrayformula(if(F2:F<>"",G2:G+max(F:F)-F2:F,))`

`F2:F<>""` evaluates the calc whilst each cell in column `F` is not empty, otherwise the `,` at the end of the formula does nothing.